# Azure App service connecting to on prem response time issues

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Hi I am trying to connect to onprem service from Azure app service via HCM, the first call after every inactive period takes 16 seconds, There after it is pretty fast, it feels like once the connection is establish APP service, HCM (hybrid connection manager) and onprem the response is faster, but once it is in the inactive state the connection might be dropped? Not sure how this works internally. My app service is linux. Has anyone had similar issues?

[image: App service settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the server certificate had a property A Certificate Revocation List  CRL and that pointed to another URL which it could not resolve, It tried connecting to it and failed silently (This took some time). To fix this i added the CRL Url to the HCM and that resolved the latency issue.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the response time:

**Step 1:**
Try to pre compile the code before deploying to azure. if you are using visual studio to deploy the project by performing right click publish and then follow the below screenshot
[image: Precompilation options]

Also check [Precompilation Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/precompiling-your-website-cs#precompilation-options) for precompiling website

And check Deploying the [precompiled website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/precompiling-your-website-cs#deploying-the-precompiled-website) on how to deploy website.

**Step 2:**

Check the **rewrite rule** of .NET Framework in web.config

```
<system.webServer>  
<rewrite>  
<rules>  
<rule name="Redirect to https"> 
<match url="(.*)"/>  
<conditions>  
<add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="Off"/>  
</conditions>  
<action type="Redirect" url="[https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1](https://medium.com/tryce-technologies/%7BHTTP_HOST%7D/%7BR:1)}"/>  
</rule>  
</rules>  
</rewrite>  
</system.webServer>
```

Due to this rule the "Always On" request will stop working

Try to write your rule in the below manner

```
 <system.webServer>  
<rewrite>  
<rules>  
**<rule name="No HTTPS for user agent AlwaysOn and Root of site" stopProcessing="true">  
<match url="^$"/>  
<conditions>  
<add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^AlwaysOn$" />  
</conditions>  
<action type="None" />  
</rule>**  
<rule name="Redirect to https">  
<match url="(.*)"/>  
<conditions>  
<add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="Off"/>  
</conditions>  
<action type="Redirect" url="[https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1](https://medium.com/tryce-technologies/%7BHTTP_HOST%7D/%7BR:1)}"/>  
</rule>  
</rules>  
</rewrite>  
</system.webServer>
```

for further issues can [refer](https://medium.com/tryce-technologies/possible-fix-when-always-on-azure-web-site-is-sometimes-slow-to-load-79ddd606f6cf)

If the Issue still persists send [HAR Traces](https://support.infogix.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019119773-How-to-generate-a-HAR-file-for-troubleshooting-network-issues-or-slowness) to find out the exact issue.